# Vagrant not running rc.local

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, vagrant

How do I make sure that when I run `vagrant up` it runs `/etc/rc.local` to set PATHS? `rc.local` file is being created like this:

```
 #!/bin/sh -e
export CONDA_DIR=/opt/conda
export PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser --notebook-dir='/home/vagrant' &
exit 0
```

It is also not setting `SPARK_HOME`

It runs when I run it manually but gets hung up on `jupyter notebook` and not EXITING.

Comment: Did you enter vagrant init before vagrant up?

Comment: @jones0610 I had adde new box, it downloaded and installed all necessary things

Comment: @jones0610 does not `init` create new `Vagrantfile`?